# "Requested module not found" error with Moment-locale.js and Moment-timezone.js in Titanium / Android

Tags: javascript, android, localization, titanium-mobile, momentjs

I need to display UTC datetime values in a given timezone and locale (language specific date-time values) within my Titanium Mobile App (Android).

I am using use both Moment-locale and Moment-Timezone for this like so in my Alloy.js..

```
//include moment.js+locale for locale specific date-time formatting
var moment = require('moment-with-locales');

//include moment-timezone.js for time zone specific date-time formatting
var momentTZ = require('moment-timezone');
```

However, as soon as I do this and run my app, I get a "Requested module not found" error. This is even before I refer these libraries and use it in my code (so there is some conflict between these libs). Here is the excerpt from my Console.

> [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [169,169] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
>   [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,170] - In ti:/module.js:280,9
>   [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [2,172] - Message: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: moment
>   [ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,173] - Source:         throw new Error("Requested module not found: " + request);
>   [INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 15.683MB for 2536932-byte allocation
>   [ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at ti:/module.js:280: Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: moment

I have been racking my brains at it but given my limited understanding of JS libraries, I have not had much luck. I suspect it is related to [this issue](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/155962/momentjs-timezone-information) but I have not figured out how to solve it. Any tips or pointers on how to solve this will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you installed the module properly?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Anand. Yes, I have the .JS file under the lib folder. If I comment out my alloy.js code for moment-timezone, then my moment-locale works just fine. I am able to convert UTC date-time to locale specific values, so I suspect that the issue is not in module installation.